# Key pad is not getting enabled in AWS device Farm, App is getting killed when it under execution

Tags: aws-device-farm

I am executing my mobile scripts across an AWS device farm. During Execution the app is being invoked but all of a sudden the app is getting closed. And I also observed Key Pad is not getting enabled when script is under execution in the AWS device. How can I solve this issue? Kindly help me out..

Comment: you will need to provide a lot more information than that for a chance to get an answer

Answer (score -1):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

The logcat from your run should point out why the app crashed. It will give you the stack trace why it is getting closed suddenly. If you share the run URL from the console we can take a closer look. Most likely it is an app crash.

Device Farm does not introduce any code with your test scripts or app execution so it does not activate or deactivate the key pad as this is not a configurable item.

Again if you share the run URL we can take a look at these errors and update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Can the moderator or the OP elaborate on why this was down voted? I would like to take care about the cause the next time.